# A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'

Tags: imagepicker

I added "image_picker: ^0.8.4+11" package to my project.
After adding it was returning this error.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:classpath'.
> Could not find gradle-3.5.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.jar

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 3):

I have similar problem , on `windows` and `Gradle:3.5.0` .

Any package that utilized this Gradle version would throw an error!

To resolve this issue, I `cleaned the cache of Gradle` in this address:

> ```
> C:\Users\<MY_ACCOUNT>\.gradle\caches
> ```

And then , `resync` the project and android module.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the gradle to latest version and the problem was solved.

Go to android\gradle\gradle-wrapper.properties and change the gradle version to the last one.